# GPFS quorum and rolling updates

Tags: ibm

I guess it's something that I am missing although I have read the GPFS documentation. 
Let's say we have a four node GPFS setup, with three of them acting as quorum. In GPFS > 3.2 we can perform rolling upgrades, but how will that work when there is no possibility of keeping a quorum; (at some point one of these three nodes will need to be upgraded).

In the internet I saw someone telling that if there is a -1 node from the quorum, the quorum will be maintained, but I haven't seen that in the redbook documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems I found an answer.

In order for a quorum to be available, you need more than half of the nodes that belong to it to be online. That means that on a quorum of 6 nodes needs 4 nodes online, or for example a quorum consisting of 3 nodes needs 2 of them to be online.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/General%20Parallel%20File%20System%20%28GPFS%29/page/Configuring%20GPFS%20for%20Reliability) is the information (go to the Node Quorum part)

Comment: I don't know about gpfs specifically, but most systems that have a concept of quorum also have a witness or quorum only type node. This node does not handle any workload but it does contribute a vote to the quorum. This could allow you to shut down more than half of your data nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In GPFS then half the quorum nodes are required for the cluster to be up.  You can indeed perform rolling upgrades on the current versions of GPFS. I have experience and have done this with 3.4 and 3.5, I'm not sure about 3.3 or earlier.

My advice for a 4 node cluster, or any cluster for that matter, would be to take one node at a time and upgrade. if you run mmgetstate -aL you'll see the current quorum state, how many quorum nodes are active and how many are required to keep the cluster up

A note for anyone else looking at this, if you have a 2 node cluster then you should look into tiebreaker disks. This means if a node is down and the remaining quorum node can see the tiebreaker disk then it will keep the cluster alive. This is vital for redundancy in a 2 node cluster but in larger clusters it's better to have 3 or 5 quorum nodes.